# Proper way to hook up a NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, textfield

I am trying to create a simple Mac OS X application which displays text output, which is logging for my program. Here is what I did:

1) Created a Mac OS X UI project

2) Added a "Text Field" component into the middle of the Application window in MainMenu.xib

3) Added a new class "MainWindow.m" with the following property:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *mainWindowText;
```

4) Connected up a "Referencing Outlet" from the text field component to the property. I now see a gray dot to the left of the above line of code

5) In my application, I create a new thread which creates an instance of MainWindow. Then I wait 5 seconds and try to access the mainWindowText variable above but it is always null. I was expecting a non-null variable so I could call setStringValue: and modify the text at any time.

I tried doing something similar with doText: and I am able to see the callback when I hit enter, and write text there. However I need a way to modify the text at an arbitrary time and I thought the above property was the proper way.

I have also tried adding a @synthesize statement, but that had no effect.

Any suggestions?

Update: After reading some posts I think the problem is that I am working with the wrong mainWindow object. I tried creating a NSObject in the NIB and making its custom class type mainWindow, and created a IBOutlet (type MainWindow *) in one of my other classes, but it would not let me wire these two things up, so I am not sure how to access this NSObject object I added to the NIB.

Answer (score 0):

The NIB file has an owner - that is the class that you want to use to do this stuff. The way things should work is:

1. Create an instance of your class (the owner, with the outlet)
2. During initialisation this class loads the NIB file
3. As the NIB file is loaded the outlet references are configured
4. A callback fires (`awakeFromNib`) to tell the owner all config is done

After that's complete, then you can access the outlets.

From the initial project you should have a NIB file and a class that is its owner so you should use that to do your controlling tasks (certainly until you have more experience with NIB archives).